# How can I remove duplicate records (It's a tricky case, the rows are not essentially unique but their content are)

Tags: sql, postgresql, duplicates

I'm a Postgres user.
I have a table with this structure:

```
CREATE TABLE ParticleInteraction
(
particle1id smallint,
particle2id smallint,
timestep smallint,
distance real
)
```

The table holds information about particles interaction.
The particles and their positions are stored in another table (we don't care about it here).
I created a SQL function to calculate the distance between the particle and store the result in the "ParticleInteraction" table.
Everything is good so far, the distance is computed and the result is stored in the table.
The problem is that the result in "ParticleInteraction" involves all the possible cases (which make the duplication):
For example, let's say we have only two particles, particleid  7 and particleid 11 and we have only one-time step.
So, the result in the table will be:

```
particle1id   particle1id   timestep   distance
7             11            1          0
11            7             1          0
```

As you can see, the two records represent the same information even though they are not unique.
We need only one of these two records.
No matter which of the two records going to be deleted.

How can I delete one of them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If they are always duplicate then just do the following

```
 delete from ParticleInteraction 
 where particle1id  > particle2id
```

However, I believe that it would be much easier to avoid storing the duplicates (using the condition `particle1id  > particle2id`).

Answer (score 1):

Here is one method:

```
delete ParticleInteraction pi
    where pi.particle2id > pi.particle1id and
          exists (select 1
                  from ParticleInteraction pi2
                  where pi2.particle2id = pi1.particle1id and
                        pi2.particle1id = pi1.particle2id and
                        pi2.timestep = pi.timestep
                 );
```

I'm not sure if you need to validate distance as well, or if you just want one row per pair per timestep.

If you don't want to modify the table and merely want a query that returns one row per particular pair, you can use `distinct on`:

```
select distinct on (least(pi.particle2id, pi.particle1id), greatest(pi.particle2id, pi.particle1id), timestamp),
       pi.*
from ParticleInteraction pi
order by least(pi.particle2id, pi.particle1id),
         greatest(pi.particle2id, pi.particle1id),
         timestep;
```

Comment: Thank you for your contribution